# mysql query broken in php

Tags: php, mysql, select, echo

I have a mySQL query in php:

```
$query = "SELECT serial FROM code WHERE type='".$type."' AND year='".$year."' AND subject='".$subject."' AND mounth='".$mounth."' AND day='".$day."' ORDER BY serial DESC LIMIT 1";
```

when I echo it (for debugging purposes) I see this:

```
SELECT serial FROM code WHERE type='in' AND year='391' AND subject='pcyear=393' AND mounth='04' AND day='1' ORDER BY serial DESC LIMIT 1
```

what is the problem near **subject='pcyear=393** ??

please help

Comment: You really need to say what the error is you are seeing! What is the data type of the subject column?

Comment: Isn't that a typo in `mounth` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet if you go back and `echo $subject` you'll get `pcyear=393`

Check and make sure that `$subject` is assigned correctly.

Comment: `pcyear=393` may be a valid subject, for all we know

Answer (score 0):

Your $subject variable is is set to `subject='pcyear=393`.